# PySimpleGUI prints several times output

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I have a problem using tabs in pysimplegui. Each time that I click in "Go" my code executes one more time than previously again and again, I mean first click in "Go" program runs once, but next time twice and so on...

[image]

```
while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    logger = monitor_logging(values['log_level'], log_path, 1000000)
    logger.warning(values['log_level'] + " log set has been established.")

    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED or event == 'Close':
        break

    if event == 'Go':

        redirect_uri = 'http://test.test.com:9015/callback/catcher'
        response = dict()

        authorize = Authorize(
            values['http_type'],
            values['server'],
            values['port'],
            values['client_id'],
            redirect_uri,
            values['loginname'],
            values['password'],
            None,  # endpoint
            None,  # header
            response,  # response
            int(values['timeout']),  # timeout must be integer
            int(values['acr_values']),  # acr values must be integer
            values['response_type'],
            values['scope'],
            values['state'],
            values['nonce'])

        authorize.http_get(values['acr_values'])  # acr_value parameter

        if authorize.response['connection_code'] == 0 \
                and 100 < len(authorize.response['requests'].text) < 110:
                    print(authorize.response['requests'].text)

        else:

            sg.popup_error('Authorize - Timeout Connection Error')

    # access all the values and if selected add them to a string

    elif event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:

        window.close()
```

Output:

```
2021-09-29 15:03:23,036 : WARNING : root : MainThread : WARNING log set has been established.
2021-09-29 15:03:23,709 : WARNING : Authorize : MainThread :        200      test.test.com:9000     .173518            lancer1@lancer.com          test
[2a2ntk39ek4rumaomulbm28hrvj7k6tvm5tdeomdvf8g273i37u8mc63vtdct4ekplevcfjie6108iq0qdqqdrbocitoc03getccntc]
2021-09-29 15:03:38,096 : WARNING : root : MainThread : WARNING log set has been established.
2021-09-29 15:03:38,096 : WARNING : root : MainThread : WARNING log set has been established.
2021-09-29 15:03:38,796 : WARNING : Authorize : MainThread :        200      test.test.com:9000     .172641            lancer1@lancer.com          test
2021-09-29 15:03:38,796 : WARNING : Authorize : MainThread :        200      test.test.com:9000     .172641            lancer1@lancer.com          test
[o35hgr6tlk4qq73glvgihd376i7lnl7m7h6qq0d5e0ghgk9la6hm1ou518rkau51100l5dq1s7iardri1mc4ttbpkmmdm19h8dt4sl]
```

The correct would be the code runs once each time that I click in "Go" and not several times as you can see above example.

Comment: "Go" just do it once, it should be caused by how you create a `logger` in function `monitor_logging` which not shown in your demo code, IMO, it may log twice or more.

Comment: Right.  The issue is that you keep adding more and more loggers.  They accumulate, so each one gets a say.  Just create the logger once.

Comment: `logger = monitor_logging(values['log_level'], log_path, 1000000)` makes a new one every time through.